# How to minimize size of Spatialite file by reducing excess projections, logging etc

Tags: spatialite

I have a spatialite db with only 1 table. It contains a million simple polygons with 8 points each and is about 350 MB. It is intended for read-only use in a mobile app, so I want to reduce the size as much as possible. To that end I don't need 500 coord systems (described in 3 different tables!), activity logs etc.

I've tried dropping the excess coord systems with a delete command but it gives a foreign key constraint error.

```
delete from spatial_ref_sys where srid <> 4326
```

Simply saving as SQLite drops the size to 86 MB so that is the size of the attributes, primary key etc.
How do I trim ALL of the fat?

Comment: do you have a database manager to view the database?  if not, I recommend dbeaver.  In the database manager(or through a shell if you prefer) you can identify all the foreign keys and relationships.  You would need to delete the  foreign key references, delete the records you don't need, then recreate the references.

Comment: hmmm. DBeaver is pretty cool, and I understand what you mean, but you can't drop a foreign key in SQLite. The usual workaround of saving as a new table is super complicated on a spatialite db.

Comment: How do you create the SpatiaLite table? The InitSpatialMetadata function has an option to create the spatial_ref_sys table as empty and InsertEpsgSrid can be used for inserting just the system that you need https://www.gaia-gis.it/stored-procs-win-test/spatialite-sql-latest.html. With GDAL you can use -dsco init_with_epsg=no. With this option only the parametert of the layer SRS will be inserted.

Comment: I created it in QGIS, where none of those options are available. I don't usually dabble in GDAL, could I use OGR2OGR to copy the contents and make the change? If so, some pointers would be great!

Comment: If you want to play with the database you can use `PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF` and then turn them back ON later. But making a copy with ogr2ogr is probably easies. Out of my head the command could look like `ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -dsco init_with_epsg=no output.sqlite input.sqlite`.

Comment: @user30184 that worked on the excess coord systems. Unfortunately it only reduced the size of the database by about 5 MB.

Comment: FYI you can create a spatialite table in QGIS without the EPSG table, but only if you create it by saving an existing layer (can be temp data) to the spatialite format, rather than going to Layer > Create Layer. If you don't need spatial functions etc. in the database would you consider geopackage as a spatially enabled version of sqlite without a lot of the extra fluff?

Comment: Minimal Spatialite db with one feature seems to require 233 472 bytes so the ballast is not huge. But SpatiaLite is not extremely compact format. The same holds with GeoPackage. You could have a try with compressed SpatiaLite geometries by using layer creation option `-lco compress_geom=yes` https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/sqlite.html. If you have XYZ geometries you may consider if XY would be enough, that saves guite a lot of space. Simplified geoemetries are of course smaller, and dropping unnecessary attributes helps a bit, but not so much if the attributes are not long strings.